Cannot access Shopify API (Custom App) from Chrome Extension
I am building a chrome extension.
I cannot access the shopify api through either basic auth, or using the 'X-Shopify-Access-Token' header.
Here is my code:
this is in background.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.contentScriptQuery == "query") {
    var url = "https://<store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json";
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'value'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(`{
  shop {
      name
  }
}`)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(r => {
        sendResponse(r);
      }).catch(error => sendResponse(error));
    return true;
  });


This is being passed to the content.js file:
function testFetch() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        contentScriptQuery: "query",
    },
    response => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        } else {
            console.log('response: ', response);
        }
    });
}

Unfortunately, the response I receive is:
response: errors {query: 'Required parameter missing or invalid'}
[[Prototype]] Object

And I cannot determine what is preventing me from accessing the Shopify API.
I've verified access scopes, I've verified the X-Shopify-Access-Token value.
Any help would be really appreciated!
Here are examples of what I've looked into:

How to make a cross-origin request in a content script (currently blocked by CORB despite the correct CORS headers)?
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/web-accessible-resources
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/samples
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/network-requests


I realised I made a very silly mistake. Here is the solution:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.contentScriptQuery == "query") {
    var url = "https://<store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json";
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'value'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: `{
  shop {
      name
  }
}`})
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(r => {
        sendResponse(r);
      }).catch(error => sendResponse(error));
    return true;
  });

I forgot to wrap the body:
JSON.stringify( `<query>` )
It should be:
JSON.stringify({ query: `<query>` })
